# 2nd uv in Aframe for ambient occlusion

Tags: java, aframe

I would like to use baked AO on an obj-model in Aframe. Don Mccurdy explains
that AO needs a 2nd UV channel and how to solve this in Java here:

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2721

I tried it but I don`t get it to work!

var geometry = mesh.geometry;

geometry.addAttribute( 'uv2', new THREE.BufferAttribute( geometry.attributes.uv.array, 2 ) );

How do I point this js-lines to my obj-model in Aframe?

Thanks a lot for help, appreciate! Best, can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, I'd suggest opening the OBJ file in Blender, [adding the Ambient Occlusion texture as described in the Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#baked-ambient-occlusion), then exporting to glTF. The rest will be handled automatically with A-Frame's `gltf-model` component, and will load more quickly.

---

If converting to another format isn't an option, you'll need to write a custom component that listens for the model to load, then traverses every mesh in the model (there might be more than one!) and creates an extra UV set:

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('copy-uvs', {
  init: function () {
    this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', function (e) {
      e.detail.model.traverse(function(object) {
        if (object.isMesh && object.geometry.attributes.uv) {
          var geometry = object.geometry;
          geometry.setAttribute('uv2', geometry.attributes.uv);
          console.log('copied UVs!');
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

This `copy-uvs` component would need to be attached to the same element as your OBJ model.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate that! Cheers, Can

Comment: It works perfectly! I`m very glad, thank you! It gives my whole scene a new level of quality!